# как вычитать '.$row["kg"].'-'.$row["tara"].'

Tags: php

как вычитать '.$row["kg"].'-'.$row["tara"].'

```
<?php
    //fetch.php
    include('database_connection.php');
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM sample_data ORDER BY id ASC";
    
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query); 
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        $total_row = $statement->rowCount();
        $output = '';
    
        if($total_row > 0)
    {
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            
            $output .= 
            
            '
            <tr>        
            
            <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["country"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["kg"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["tara"].'</td>
        
        
            
            </tr> 
            '
            ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center">Пусто</td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }
    
    echo $output;
    
    ?>
```

[image: скрин ответа]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...' . ($row["kg"] - $row["tara"]) . '...`
```

Comment: kg=23500
tara=9840

ответ запроса  ' . ($row["kg"] - $row["tara"]) . ' =       -9840

Comment: как проверял данный ответ?

Comment: через сайт (веб сервер)

Comment: как именно? Отладкой?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: @Алексей-Шиманский на сайте есть скрипт через ajax идёт запрос на php  отработчик.  php  отработчик  отправляеть на бд и получаю резултать в виде html  $output .= 
            
            '
            <tr>        
            
            <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["country"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["kg"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["tara"].'</td>
        
        
            
            </tr> 

и ещё добавил скрин сайта

Comment: @MLSALA ну окей. где тут тот код, что я написал и как убедился например,, что у тебя kg не меньше, чем tara?

Comment: @MLSALA очевидно ты так скопировал код....например все эти многоточия только для того, чтобы показать, что там у тебя ещё какие-то данные были....а ты всё скопировал вслепую зачем-то

Comment: @Алексей-Шиманский  foreach($result as $row)
 {
  
  $output .= 
  
  '
  <tr>  
  <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row["country"].'</td>
  <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["tara"].'</td>
  <td> '.($row["kg"] - $row["tara"]).' </td>
  </tr> 
  '
  ;
 }

Comment: @MLSALA https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482 вот отладчик, посмотри что у тебя на каждой строке происходит.... у тебя на текущий момент получается что первый аргумент всегда 0